# Is Chanakya vishnu amsa?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

I have heard that Chanakya's mother strived for children for almost 14 years and later, Chanakya was born.

He was a great contributor for indian economics and much more.
I knew very little about him.

So, I also heard that he was an amsa of lord vishnu.

Is it correct?

Comment: There are several claims like these, with likes of *Sai Baba* & several other local enlightened beings, attributed to be *amsa or partial incarnation* of various different deities, as per local folklore and stories only.

Comment: I see.. @vivikta